# Conflict between auto sliding and bullet navigation sliding(Only one works at a time)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to Jquery and I tried to create my own slider which will

1. slide automatically in given time interval
2. Slide when the bullet navigation is clicked
3. Navigation active state changes automatically when auto slide is running
4. Active link changes when user clicks on bullet navigation.

The code I have tried is given below. Forgive if its not straight and simple as I am new to this. The portion that I have commented in Jquery is for auto sliding.

***Issue : When I uncomment the autosliding code the bullet navigation is not working and vice versa. Only one works at a time. Please help me with this. Thank you.***

https://jsfiddle.net/Kowshikan/ac46y9do/

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="newsFeed">
 <h3> Our Latest News </h3>
    <ul id="slideBox">
        <!--  slide 1 -->
        <li id="1"> 
            Content 1
        </li>

        <!--  slide 2 -->
        <li id="2">     
            Content 2
        </li>

        <!--  slide 3 -->
        <li id="3"> 
            Content 3
        </li>

        <!--  slide 4 -->
        <li id="4"> 
            Content 4
        </li>

        <!--  slide 5 -->
        <li id="5"> 
            Content 5
        </li>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </ul>

    <!--  Pagination -->
    <div class="pager">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#newsFeed
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slideBox
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#slideBox li
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 336px;
}
.pager
{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    min-height: 65px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}
.pager ul
{
    padding: 10px;
}
.pager a 
{
    color: #444 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(center top , #FFF 0%, #F0F0F0 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #FFF 0%, #F0F0F0 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFF 0%, #F0F0F0 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
.pager a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.pagerActive
{
    background: linear-gradient(center top , #eeeeee 0%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #eeeeee 0%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #eeeeee 0%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb !important;
}
.pager li
{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #777;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: linear-gradient(center top , #FFF 0%, #EEE 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #FFF 0%, #EEE 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFF 0%, #EEE 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 3px;
}
.pager li:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        totalslide = $('#slideBox li').length;
        slidewidth = $('#newsFeed').width();
        var totalwidth = slidewidth * totalslide;
        $('#slideBox').css({'width': totalwidth});
        $('#slideBox li').css({'width': slidewidth});
        $('.pager li:first').addClass('pagerActive');

        /* setInterval(function () {
                autoslide();
        }, 2000); */

        $('.pager li').click(function(){
            var slide = ($(this).html() - 1) * slidewidth;
            $('#slideBox').animate({right: slide}, 500);
            $('.pager li').removeClass('pagerActive');
            $(this).addClass('pagerActive');
        });
    });

    /* function autoslide() 
    {
        $('#slideBox li').each(function(index){
            $('#slideBox').delay(2000).animate({right: slidewidth*index}, 500);
        });
    } */

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What you need to change to make it work:

- Don't call the animation for each `li` element, one time is enough.
- Don't delay the animation if you already have set an interval.
- Notify to your `autoslide()` function which is the active slide, so it can pass to the next one properly.

### What you can consider to change:

- If both `autoslide()` and `$('.pager li').click(function()` are going to make the same work, isolate that code in a separated function.
- When calculating the `totalwidth` of the `'#slideBox'`, note that you are not considering the `padding` and the `border` of the slides. Due to that they are not fitting inside and the last one jump to the next line.
- I would advise more self explanatory names for the *id* attributes.

I leave you a snippet with all these changes:

```js
var totalslide = $( '#slideBox li' ).length;
var slidePadding = parseInt( $( '#slideBox li' ).css( 'padding-left' ) );
var slideBorder = parseInt( $( '#slideBox li' ).css( 'border-left-width' ) );
var slidewidth = $( '#newsFeed' ).width();
var slideRealWidth = slidewidth + 2 * ( slidePadding + slideBorder );
var totalwidth = totalslide * slideRealWidth;

$( '#slideBox' ).css( {'width': totalwidth} );
$( '#slideBox li' ).css( {'width': slidewidth} );
$( '.pager li:first' ).addClass( 'pagerActive' );

setInterval( function () {
    autoslide();
}, 2000 ); 

function setActiveSlide ( activePager ) {
    $( '.pager li' ).removeClass( 'pagerActive' );
    $( '#pager' + activePager ).addClass( 'pagerActive' );
    var currentWidth = slideRealWidth * ( activePager - 1 );
    $( '#slideBox' ).animate( {right: currentWidth }, 500);
}

$( '.pager li' ).click (function() {
    var activePager = parseInt( $(this).html() );
    setActiveSlide( activePager );
});

function autoslide() {
    var activePager = parseInt( $('.pagerActive').html() );
    var nextPager = ( activePager > 4 )? 1 : activePager + 1;
    setActiveSlide( nextPager );
}
```

```css
#newsFeed {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slideBox {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#slideBox li {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
.pager {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    min-height: 65px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}
.pager ul {
    padding: 10px;
}
.pager a {
    color: #444 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(center top, #FFF 0%, #F0F0F0 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #FFF 0%, #F0F0F0 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFF 0%, #F0F0F0 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
.pager a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.pagerActive {
    background: linear-gradient(center top, #eeeeee 0%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #eeeeee 0%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #eeeeee 0%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb !important;
}
.pager li {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #777;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: linear-gradient(center top, #FFF 0%, #EEE 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #FFF 0%, #EEE 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFF 0%, #EEE 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 3px;
}
.pager li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="newsFeed">
    <h3> Our Latest News </h3>
    <ul id="slideBox">
     <!--  slide 1 -->
     <li id="slide1"> 
      Content 1
     </li>  
     <!--  slide 2 -->
     <li id="slide2">  
      Content 2
     </li>    
     <!--  slide 3 -->
     <li id="slide3"> 
      Content 3
     </li>   
     <!--  slide 4 -->
     <li id="slide4"> 
      Content 4
     </li>   
     <!--  slide 5 -->
     <li id="slide5"> 
      Content 5
     </li>
     <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </ul>
    <!--  Pagination -->
    <div class="pager">
     <ul>
      <li id="pager1">1</li>
      <li id="pager2">2</li>
      <li id="pager3">3</li>
      <li id="pager4">4</li>
      <li id="pager5">5</li>
     </ul>
     <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

---

**UPDATE**:

As requested in your comment, I will explain the following code. Btw, now that you made me think about it, it is more elegant and maintainable to replace `> 4` for `>= totalslide`.

```
var nextPager = ( activePager >= totalslide )? 1 : activePager + 1;
/* equivalent to:
if ( activePager >= totalslide )
    // if we have reached the last slide, we come back to the first one
    nextPager = 1;
else
    // if not, we go to the next one
    nextPager = activePager + 1;
*/

// Invoking setActiveSlide function passing nextPager (the index of the next slide)
setActiveSlide( nextPager );
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for the clear explanation. This is my very first question in stack overflow. It helped me a lot. Thank you. :)

Comment: `var nextPager = ( activePager > 4 )? 1 : activePager + 1;  
setActiveSlide( nextPager );`  
Can you please explain this code alone ?

Comment: Got it David. Thanks a lot. Most helpful.

Comment: @Kowshikan: Glad it helped!